# Alternatives To ifelse statement

Tags: r, if-statement

So if I have a vector with a column named "Question" which has two inputs either "no" or "yes" I want to know if there is a way to calculate specific varibles depending on whether questions is either yes or no.

The idea is that I could do:

```
Question <- c("No","No","Yes","Yes")
if(Question=="yes"){
X <- [1:5]
z <- [2:6]
test1 <- rbind(X,z)
}
if(Question=="no"){
X <- [1:4]
z <- [3:6]
test1 <- rbind(X,z)
}
```

Right now this is not possible because "Question" is a vector and I was wondering if there is a way to do this besides using ifelse statement. T

The desired output would be the row combination of X and z. I know that I cannot do the if statement as is. Because other it has multiple inputs.

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: Your code is not valid syntax, which makes it hard to guess what it is supposed to do. Please describe that in words and show the expected output for your example input.

Comment: It's still not clear what your desired output is.   I see that each individual if-test gives an 8x1 matrix.  Is the desired result (1) a list of 4 8x1 matrices; (2) a 32x1 matrix; (3) an 8x4 matrix ... (4) ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you're looking for is a for loop. This can be used to apply an if-then statement to every element of a vector, as opposed to the vector itself, as so:

```
for(x in Question) {
  if(x == "Yes") {
    *output*
  } else if(x == "No") {
    *output*
  }
}
```

I'm not really sure what your end goal is so I don't know what should go in those if statements, but hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Comment: You almost certainly shouldn't use a `for` loop here. Using a `for` loop is an exception in R. Usually, there is a better (more efficient) solution.

Comment: Have a suggestion then...? Because this is what I would do and it works pretty well for me.

Comment: Specific questions get specific answers. I can't give a suggestion without knowing exactly what they want to do, but I know that this very likely isn't the best way. If you are in the habit of using `for` loops in R, you write slow code.

Comment: What are some general best practices to avoid using them in situations like these? Because that is something I'm in the habit of at the moment.